# ByteArray or InputStream to File-Object

Tags: java, file, io, inputstream

I try to get a File from a InputStream out of my jar-file.
My Methode is return an InputStream or an byte[]. But I need a File-Object. I wont save the File with an FileOutputStream.

Is there a chance to get it?

Comment: Not clear what you need, be more descriptive please

Answer (score 0):

An entry in a Jar file *isn't* a File, or a file. It is a resource, and can be obtained as a URL or InputStream via the resource APIs. What you want does not exist.

Comment: The same i found out right now. I have to save the file.